# Fill column with value until last row

Tags: excel, vba

My code should copy data from excel file TimeSheet. Each file contains header with person name, and blocks with daily records. Code is looping all excel file in folder and appending records to master file. Code was partly solved here. But now I have problem with filling out column A with Person name.

Code should first fill column B in NewSht with tasks and later grab value from filed B7 OldSht and copy it to first empty cell in column A NewSht and fill until last Row in column B. With current code I get

> 'Autofill method of Range class failed'

error.

```
Sub AllFiles()

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim OldSht As Worksheet
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim target As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

' set master workbook
Set Masterwb = Workbooks("result2.xlsm")

folderPath = "C:\Users\TimeSheets2019\inside" 'contains folder path

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx*")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set NewSht = Masterwb.Worksheets("Tabelle1") ' added
    Set OldSht = wb.Worksheets("Manager Form") ' added

    ' get the first empty row in the new sheet
    Set FindRng = NewSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    Set target = NewSht.Cells(NewSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
LastRow = NewSht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'copy taks list to column B            
    OldSht.Range("B7:B15, B17:B26").Copy
    NewSht.Cells(NewSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
' copy person name until last row in coulmn B
    OldSht.Range("B5").AutoFill Destination:=NewSht.Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    wb.Close False

Exit_Loop:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Filename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[TimeSheet to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dswKb.png)

[Results in Master file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNZGU.png)

Comment: `OldSht.Range("B5").AutoFill Destination:=NewSht.Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault` doesn't the autofill range have to be include the source cell?

Comment: The autofill destination has to include the source range. Do you need to autofill or to copy/paste values?

Comment: @BigBen is right. According to the documentation [Range.AutoFill method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill) *"The destination must include the source range."*

Comment: @BigBen i was just editing that to be "inclusive" of the source cell as you posted.

Comment: autofill should copy value from OldSht (each file has separate name of person) and fill it in NewSht next to list of tasks that has bean already copied.

Comment: @Eve That is not how autofill works (refer to the linked documentation). Autofill cannot do that. Please [edit] your question and include screenshots of your original data and how it should look afterwards.

Comment: my source range is OldSht.Range("B5"). If autofill cannot do that maybe you have other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, [`Range.AutoFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill) only works if the destination range includes the source range. You can't autofill from one sheet to another.

I think you just need a simple value transfer here:

```
NewSht.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = OldSht.Range("B5").Value
```

Comment: Yes it works, but how to replace "A2:A" with first empty row? Currently it fills correctly names for fist file, and for second it transfer name to A1 cell which is header

Comment: That sounds like `LastRow` is 1, which is not what you expect. Is there any data in column B? Do you need to find the last row *after* you've pasted the data into column B?

Comment: Yes @BigBen, that was idea that first it copies list of tasks to column B, and then add Name to column A until then end, and then the same with rest of files

Comment: Then move `LastRow = NewSht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` after the copy step.

Comment: Great @BigBen thanks a lot, and how replace "A2:A" so it starts with first empty row in column A, instead with A2?

Comment: You can use pretty much the same way you got `LastRow`, like `StartingRow = NewSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. Then you can do `"A" & StartingRow & ":A" & LastRow`.